# Spring framework bean error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, javabeans

I am trying to learn Spring in java. I am stuck at the beginning when i run the fist program.
**i am trying to call the `draw` method of the Triangle class** . 
But i am seeing many errors.

In the `DrawingApp.java` class eclipse is showing some warning - ( `The type XmlBeanFactory is deprecated` ).

I am providing my implementation along with errors below.

**Triangle.java**

```
package org.hemant.spring;

public class Triangle {

public void draw(){
    System.out.println("Triangle drawn");   
 }
}
```

**DrawingApp.java**

```
package org.hemant.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingApp {

 /**
 * @param args
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new   FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));

    Triangle triangle = (Triangle)factory.getBean("Triangle.class");
    triangle.draw();
    }

}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE bean PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"     "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-bean-2.0.dtd">

<bean>
  <bean id="triangle" class="org.hemant.spring.Triangle"/>
</bean>
```

**Errors**

```
     Apr 16, 2016 12:33:45 PM     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader    loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file  [C:\Users\hemant001\workspace_mars_eclipse\spring tutorial\spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main"   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException  parsing XML document from file [C:\Users\hemant001\workspace_mars_eclipse\spring  tutorial\spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:  http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-bean-2.0.dtd
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefiniti ons(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:408)
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init> (XmlBeanFactory.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init> (XmlBeanFactory.java:66)
at org.hemant.spring.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:17)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-bean-2.0.dtd
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 5 more
```

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: i have put the error now, plz help - @PeterRader

Comment: Could it be that `factory.getBean("Triangle.class");` should be `factory.getBean("triangle");` ?

Comment: Oh, you added an error log.  It says that your xml is wrong.  You have `<bean><bean id="triangle"....></bean>` and it should be `<beans><bean id="triangle"....></beans>`.  Perhaps there is other errors.

Comment: ohhh...sorry, yes it would be factory.getBean("triangle"); , but still errors are same ??? - @JoseLuis

Comment: i changed it <beans><bean id="triange........."/></beans> , but still errors are same ?? - @JoseLuis

Comment: @hemant You have two answers to your question.  I hope they could help to you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-bean-2.0.dtd` with `http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd`  (notice *beans*, not *bean*) in your `spring.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bean PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"     "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-bean-2.0.dtd">
<bean>
  <bean id="triangle" class="org.hemant.spring.Triangle"/>
</bean>
```

should be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
      <bean id="triangle" class="org.hemant.spring.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

Also, like mentioned in the comments, `factory.getBean("Triangle.class");` should be `factory.getBean("triangle");`

For context, I'd rather do

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

...

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring.xml"); // or FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, if .xml is not in class path

        Triangle obj = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
```

And why are you using version 2.0 of Spring (based on your dtd)? That's *really* old.

Comment: Better use `getBean(Triangle.class)`

Comment: new exception thrown - Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from file [C:\Users\hemant001\workspace_mars_eclipse\spring tutorial\spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 72; The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound. - @eis

Comment: @Hemant you're right, forgot one line from my .xml example. I've added now. `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is the thing I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please do not use `XmlBeanFactory` anymore, use the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` because it seperates the reader from the factory and represent a more clean OOD.
2. It is not realy a error, its a format-problem with the configuration (i work that out to explain why eclipse not giving you a messages). You see, a configuration that could not be read is not a error. This means your application works great (be proud of your first try), but the configuration is wrong! To solve the configuration drop that doctype and ns.
3. `Triangle triangle = (Triangle)factory.getBean("Triangle.class");` will not find a definition. Use `Triangle triangle = factory.getBean(Triangle.class);` instead because you have not to cast.

So the `main` should be like this:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(factory);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));
Triangle triangle = factory.getBean(Triangle.class);
triangle.draw();
```

Comment: Good idea. But i did like to explain why eclipse is showing a warning about the class is deprecated. Oh wait `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` may automatically reload the xml.

Comment: yeaa.....its done - thank a lot -  @eis